# If silver nanoparticles kill bacteria by penetrating the cell membrane, why don't they also kill human cells on contact?

Tags: microbiology

Apparently, the silver from the nanoparticles can penetrate the cell wall of bacteria and kill them from the inside. Why, then, doesn't the same happen to human cells, e.g. the skin on my foot when I wear nanosilver-coated antibacterial socks, or the stomach lining when people drink nanosilver-treated water? Is it because the cell wall is different in bacteria than in multicellular organisms?

Answer (score 1):

1. The nanoparticles from your sock will most certainly not reach to your foots cell *membrane* (Walls are for plants/fungi)  because of the thick layer of dead skin, oils, than about 30 cell thick cornified layer (stratum corneum) build up from practically dead cells (with no nuclei or organelles) but lots of filamentous keratine. This is the most outer shell of your *epidermis* followed by layers and layers of 4 other tissue types , then comes the "actual" skin *dermis* and the *hypodermis* beneath.

[image]

2. If some of the silver-sock -nanoparticles would actually make it through there to basal tissue and reach the cells plasmamembrane, they enter via endocytosis, and start to release Ag+ they break all kinds of things, because Ag+ is cytotoxic it induces ROS, damages you Mitochondira, disturb some pathways... you get the point.
3. However this was proven to happen within human *in vitro* celllines.

> a few *in vivo* studies showed that Ag-NPs cause adverse effects on reproduction, malformations, and morphological deformities indifferent non-mammalian animal model.

Says "Review: A systematic review on silver nanoparticles-induced cytotoxicity: Physicochemical properties and perspectives

https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jare.2017.10.008

Comment: conclusion, definitely enough evidence to be suspicious, but don't freak out, just change socks daily, wash feet and don't drink dubious solutions or liquids. (sunscreen could be a factor )

Comment: I'm not freaking out, just wondering. :)
So, in the case of skin contact, I'm protected by a layer of dead skin, OK.
But there are disinfectant sprays with nanosilver, meant to be applied to open wounds. And disinfected water that goes to your stomach.
Is it actually killing both bacteria and your cells, but you're fine because your cells get replaced? Or what's the idea?